# adds leading zero to a column value Etext template

Tags: bi-publisher

How to format the column so that it adds leading zero to a column value.
for example , in the etext template i want to add this logic. using which function can i do this ?

that is if job_code is 2900 then it should come as 002900. I tried adding "0000000" under the format column, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the column in Data Model sql so it comes to the template already formated..
Select LPAD(COLUMN_NAME, 6, '0') as ALIAS...
Here is an example of LPAD function: [ERROR: Function SUBSTR requires a character expression as argument 1. and adding zeroes in front of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164722/error-function-substr-requires-a-character-expression-as-argument-1-and-adding#73165192)